# Reflection "on" or "in" a ripple?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Example sentence:

> He watched his reflection fade on/in a ripple.

Should it be *on* or *in* (or it doesn't matter)? And why?

Comment: A ripple is a fast-moving phenomenon. It doesn't provide a stationary surface in which something can be seen to fade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither "on" nor "in" really makes sense.

We might use either for a reflective object, but if we choose "on" we usually have to specify the reflective surface itself: "He watched his reflection *on the surface of* the pond" or "He watched his reflection *in* the pond." "On the pond" isn't idiomatic, nor is "on a mirror."

The problem is that a ripple, on a reflective liquid surface, disturbs the reflection. I'm guessing that the intended meaning is something like "He watched his reflection fade *into* ripples." In this case we're no longer saying anything about what the reflection was on/in (it's understood), but saying what it transformed into.